# Fourier inverse of a function to get dirac

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to get the dirac function from a fourier inverse tranform:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-iw(x-x_0)}dw$$

It is this last step I am stuck on to get the conclusion.

Original function:  $$f(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{iwx_0}$$

Comment: This integral is not convergent, as expected. The definition of the Fourier transform for non-integrable functions is not the "usual integral".

Comment: I agree, so is it a matter of I have to recognize the form and acknowledge that the Dirac arises from it?

Comment: No, you need to use the correct definition of a Fourier transform in this case. The Dirac is *not* a real valued function, but either a measure or a distribution (in both cases, a functionnal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to know a bit about generalized functions for this type of integral to make sense.

The generalized function $1(x)$ can be defined by the sequence $1_n(x)=\exp(-x^2/n^2)$. The identification with $1$ comes from the limit,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) 1_n(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d}x,$$

for sufficiently well behaved functions $f$ (e.g. infinitely differentiable with $f(x) = O(x^{-N})$ for all $N>0$).

We can define the Fourier transform of $1(x)$ as the generalized function defined by the sequence obtained from ordinary Fourier transforms of $1_n(x)$.

If we actually compute this we will find that,

$$ F(1_n)(p) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-2\pi i p x) 1_n(x) dx = \sqrt{\pi n^2}  \exp(-n^2 p^2 \pi^2) = \delta_n(p)$$

Since $\delta_n(p)$ is a sequence of $``$good functions$"$ which define the generalized function $\delta(x)$ (aka the Dirac Delta Function) we say that the Fourier transform of $1(x)$ is $\delta(x)$.

What you are missing in your integration is that you're actually trying to leave the function as $e^{i\omega x_0}$ when it should be $e^{i \omega x_0} 1_n(x)$.

Comment: whoa. Definitely wasn't expecting an explanation of that complexity. That is something I'm going to have to investigate after my exam. Where would be a good place to start to get an understanding of what you just explained. This is my first course in PDEs

Comment: @dc3rd The main ideas here are the definition of a distribution, the definition of a tempered distribution, and the definition of the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution. The first two are pretty straightforward to look up. For the last one, the Fourier transform is defined by $\langle \hat{d},\phi \rangle = \langle d,\hat{\phi} \rangle$ (up to a normalization constant depending on your definition of the Fourier transform; for the unitary FT, the constant is $1$). Here $\langle d,\phi \rangle$ is just notation for the application of the distribution $d$ to the test function $\phi$.

Comment: @dc3rd (Cont.) This tells you that the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta is a distribution which takes $\phi$ and returns $\hat{\phi}(0)$.

Comment: @dc3rd, http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0521091284/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?qid=1428793451&sr=8-2&keywords=Introduction+to+theory+of+generalised+functions

Comment: @Spencer : I think for PDE, the theory of distributions is more adapted than the theory of generalised functions, even if this approach is valid and interesting ;)

Comment: @Tryss, certainly true :). I like the theory of generalised functions because it is elementary and allows begginers to have some rigorous proofs under their belts even if they still aren't ready for the theory of distributions.

Comment: Actually, the most important part that needs to be hammered is : "the dirac is not an usual function, you can't do usual stuff with it". And you need to hit with a really big hammer, especially at physicists :p

Answer (score 3):

A correct way to do this with the formalism of the distributions:

Let $T \in \mathcal S'$ , then $\hat{T}$,the Fourier transform of $T$ is defined by

$$\forall \varphi \in \mathcal S, \langle \hat{T}, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, \hat{\varphi} \rangle $$

So the Fourier transform of $\delta_{x_0}$ is given by

$$\forall \varphi \in \mathcal S, \langle \hat{\delta_{x_0}}, \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta_{x_0}, \hat{\varphi} \rangle = \hat{\varphi}(x_0) $$

Then, as $\varphi$ is a perfectly regular function, we use the definition of the Fourier transform of $\varphi$ by an integral :

$$\hat{\varphi}(x_0) =  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(t) e^{-itx_0}dt$$

Hence

$$\forall \varphi \in \mathcal S , \langle \hat{\delta_{x_0}}, \varphi \rangle = \langle \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-itx_0}, \varphi \rangle$$

So you have $\hat{\delta_{x_0}} = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-itx_0} $

You can do it in the other direction, but the calculs are less immediate